# working with JPA repository queries

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

If this works:

```
repo.findFirstByConversionIncomeAmountLessThanEqualOrderByConversionIncomeAmountDesc(...);
```

and this works:

```
repo.findFirstByConversionEffectiveDateLessThanEqualOrderByConversionIncomeAmountDesc(...);
```

why does this generate null?

```
repo.findFirstByConversionIncomeAmountLessThanEqualAndConversionEffectiveDateLessThanEqualOrderByConversionIncomeAmountDesc(...);
```

if I understand this correctly, it should be the same as

```
select top 1 *
from conversions
where income_amount <= ?1
  and effective_date <= ?2
order by income_amount desc
```

There *is* a record that would satisfy the query.

-- edit --

Oh, yes, the "conversion" in the method name is necessary as I'm actually asking for an embedded object's values.

Comment: It look like it should work. Can you try to configure logging so you get generated sql statements?

Comment: I did - that particular method/query produced no sql statement; I don't know why.  However, I have since confirmed that it was an issue with this particular arrangement of criteria coupled with the "First" limiter is an issue.  I actually filed a [bug report](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-781)